# CSS3 Animations trigger others dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have some CSS3 animations that play in an infinite loop upon page load.

Is there a way, to trigger these manually - for example if I were to hover over *another* DOM element, without the need for Javascript/Jquery?

i.e -> hover over element a -> starts animations on DOM elements x,y,z

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it up as a `class` in your CSS and then use javascript to trigger add/remove.

```
$('#element1').hover(function(){
  $('#element2').addClass('animate');
}, function(){
  $('#element2').removeClass('animate');
});
```

In order to hook into events, you're going to need Javascript.

Another way you could do it using pure CSS is to use the pseudo class `:hover`, but only if `#element2` is a child of `#element1`.

```css
#element1:hover #element2{
  /* Your animation */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DOM would need to be set up so that x, y, and z are inside element a. Then you could do:

```
a:hover x,y,z {
    animation:yourAnimation 5s infinite;
}
```